# Batch-convert ODG to AI, CDR or JPG

Tags: conversion, openoffice, adobe-illustrator, coreldraw

My wife has a medium-sized batch (around 100) of ODG files she needs to send to a print shop.

Since they won't take ODG files, we've sent hi-res JPG in the past. However, this is tedious because we weren't able to export JPGs with a high-DPI setting (we need 300, when exporting it looks like 75).

So, our current workaround is:

- Manually export to PDF from OOo
- Manually import to GIMP
- Save as JPG

**Is there a way to automate or improve this process?**

Exporting to either format is acceptable. I have Windows and Linux boxes available.

Comment: Your print shop doesn't take pdfs?

Comment: It wasn't mentioned... they probably do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, turns out there's an extension to fix the DPI issue in OOo: http://extensions.services.openoffice.org/en/project/EnhancedGraphicExportDialogs

Answer (score 0):

ImageMagick will convert to/from odg as well. Don't know if it will handle your specific BPI issues, but it might be worth looking into.

Comment: I tried `convert file.odg file.jpg` and I got: *Magick: no decode delegate for this image format `Hoja01B.odg' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/532.
Magick: missing an image filename `Hoja01B.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/2949.*

Answer (score 0):

On win7, using LO 4.1 I had to do the following (from command line, you probably need to convert `%f` to `%%f` if running in a cmd script):

```
set path=%path%;C:\Program Files (x86)\LibreOffice 4\program
for %f in (*.odg) do (
    soffice.exe --headless --convert-to jpg --outdir "C:\tmp" %f
)
```

Notes:

- it will NOT work if any instance of LO is open!
- outdir IS required
- wildcards for input files are NOT supported (hence the for loop)

(copied my answer from ask.libreoffice )